# PHP Mail, multiple additional paramaters

Tags: php, email

I have a small mail script I'm developing for work and need to set multiple additional parameters in the mail() function.

I currently have it looking like this:

```
mail($too,$subject,$message,$headers,"O DeliveryMode=b", "-fscheduling@website.com")
```

As you can see I need both O DeliveryMode=b and -fscheduling@website.com included in the additional parameters, I've tried multiple different formats but it seems it will only accept one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

[mail](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mail.php) only accepts one argument for `$additional_parameters`.  You are putting two with:

`"O DeliveryMode=b", "-fscheduling@website.com"`

Does this work?

`"-O DeliveryMode=b -fscheduling@website.com"`

Comment: For some reason this seems to accept the -f parameter but not the delivery mode parameter. If I put the delivery mode parameter in on it's own that seems to work just fine :S

Comment: @user3750017 Do you have access to your ini file?

Comment: @user3750017 What about using PHPMailer as an alternative?  It offers much more comprehensive features than mail().